# Identify little green long legged bug

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image]

Discovered attempting to hide on bathroom sink handle at night, though bathroom light had been left on.

Barely reacted to attempts to capture it at all. No flying. No jumping. Just really slow crawling.

Found Eastern US. 2017/11/18

[image: updated image]

Comment: Please update question time of year it was found. If you have a better picture, please upload that, too.

Comment: looks like the nymph of some species of Hemipteran. Hold on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The photo is not high quality, but the shape and size of the insect definitely point towards it being the nymph of some species of [**assassin bug**](http://www.uky.edu/Ag/CritterFiles/casefile/insects/bugs/assassin/assassin.htm) (order hemiptera, family [Reduviidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduviidae)).

See this as an example:

[image]

Specifically, your specimen looks similar to [one found in a home in Virginia](https://www.whatsthatbug.com/2017/11/08/assassin-bug-bites-toddler/).

The genus is likely [***Zelus***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zelus_(bug)), and based on it's greenish hue, I'd say it's an individual of the eastern US's most common species of *Zelus*, [***Zelus luridus***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zelus_luridus) (**Pale Green Assassin Bug**).

[image]

<sup>Source: Christine Hanrahan</sup>

- Nymphs are solid green, wingless, and with narrow bodies

  > The most reliable feature to distinguish this species from others is the pair of spines on the rear corners of the pronotum. These spines are long on the lighter colored individuals and shorter on ones that are darker. It can also be distinguished by dark bands on the distal ends of the femurs, but these can often be too light to be easily seen. [[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zelus_luridus)].